# MVC: Make model parameter required only on certain views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, annotations, required

After defining a parameter for a model

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "No null")]
[DisplayName("Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

is it posible to change the properties of this parameters for certain view? For example, I want these properties (the required property) to hold for view1,view2 and view3 but not for view4. Can I disable this property for view3?

Comment: Uh... that sounds like a violation of the MVC process where your controller/model shouldn't know anything about or care what the view does.  If one view mode shouldn't see some property, perhaps it shouldn't use the same controller/model either.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: Sounds like you need a DIFFERENT viewmodel for View3 :)

Answer (score 6):

> is it posible to change the properties of this parameters for certain view?

No, attributes are baked into the assembly at compile time.

The correct way to do this is to use view models:

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EditViewModel
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "No null")]
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and your respective controller actions that will be called upon submiting forms from the 2 views will work with the view models:

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel model)
{
    ... the name will not be required here
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }
}


public ActionResult Edit(EditViewModel model)
{
    ... the name will be required here
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }
}
```

Alternative approaches would include custom model binders or implementing `IValidatableObject` interfaces and do some dynamic validation based on the current action. In two words you are heading towards the abyss. Personally this is not something I would mess with but if you want feel free to explore in that direction if you don't like my recommended solution.

Comment: So if Name had a MaxLength on the Model, you would have the same attribute on each view model as well? And any attributes on Model you want everywhere, would be duplicated as well?

Comment: For the common properties use an abstract base view model class and then have the special ones inherit from the base one.